# #value! when adding empty spaces

Tags: excel

I keep getting #value! when trying to add several cells together. E.g. A1+B1+C1

Problem is that those cells begins with IFERROR(*example*,"") and ends with an array ctrl+shift+enter. Im trying to get the cells A1 to C1 to show a "" when there's an error so it isn't so messy.

*In reality, A1 to C1 are actually 20 over cells and the formula used is either minus or plus.

However, the blanks trigger #value! and the only way seems to be replacing "" with a 0 value. Anyone know of a workaround for this or am I bound to this solution.

[image: an example of what A1,B1,C1 actually contains]

[image: A1, B1,C1 cell results]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should use `IFERROR(example,0)`. If you don't want to display the zero, you can use a [custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68), something like `# ##0;-# ##0;`
The idea in the sample above is to have a **third part** that is **empty**, hence the final `;`.
Note that my Excel has european regional settings, your separator may be different.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work when the 0 comes as a result of a formula. Typing 0 in the cell and using the custom format will remove it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SUM(A1:C1)` function instead of `A1+B1+C1`. Assuming that `B1` is blank (e.g. `=IFERROR(1/0,"")`) then:

[image]

`SUM` function will ignore any non-numeric values and give you the proper result:

[image]

See [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/sum-function-043e1c7d-7726-4e80-8f32-07b23e057f89) "Best Practices with SUM" section for more info.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me; perhaps because i forgot to mention those cells "A1,B1,C1" uses an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter). 

Also, sum may not be the best option because there's some subtraction used as well

Comment: Thanks for checking - do you mean that your sum `(=A1+B1+C1)` is actually an array formula? Can you update your question and paste a screenshot? As for the subtractions, you can simply use something like `=SUM(A1,B1,-C1)`

Comment: I've attached a screenshot; yes it is an array formula

Comment: Thanks for that; I'm still a little bit confused as it all works for me. I pasted your formula into cell B1 (see [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1ME41bA.png)) and then in cell A3 I have the following formula - `=SUM(A1,B1,-C1)`. As you can see it still displays the result properly.

Comment: yes, i just tried replicating your cells and they work just fine. For mine though, even simplifying the additions to just 2 cells A1 and B1, still causes the #value error

Comment: very odd, because A1,B1,C1 works just fine and i can even change the iferror(example,"") to numbers and it would display fine

Comment: Can you share with me the formulas you have in cells A1 and B1, plus a screenshot of their results? I'll try to recreate the issue on my side.

Comment: =IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$BV$1000,MATCH($C3,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1001&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$1001,0),(MATCH("BAF03",Sheet2!$A$1:$BV$1,0))+1),"")=0,"",IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$BV$1000,MATCH($C3,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1001&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$1001,0),(MATCH("BAF03",Sheet2!$A$1:$BV$1,0))+1),""))

i've attached a ss of the results, they are all numbers but could ofcourse be blanks if they were iferror proc-ed

Comment: Can you show me where the `SUM` formula is returning `#VALUE` error, as I cannot see it on the screenshot? In the meantime, you can also try to use the following Array formula: `=SUM(IF(ISERROR(A1:C1),"",A1:C1))`

Comment: As per Excel documentation: `If AVERAGE or SUM refer to cells that contain #VALUE! errors, the formulas will result in a #VALUE! error.`. See [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/8y0VBkD.png)

Comment: added the ss; guess there's no workaround then, might have to skip this solution. Iferror was meant to be my catch-all for errors.

Comment: I really do not see where the issue is, sorry. As you can see on my [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/MEiYwzF.png) the last formula that I provided is working fine... P.S. You should update your original question with the screenshot, instead of editing my post :-)